# should I escape a literal url added in functions.php

Tags: security, escaping

I added a snippet to my functions.php file to add credit card icons in the woocommerce checkout page. The icons are in my media library so I added the url of the image.
This is not an input and it will not be changed, should I escape it anyway?

the code:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'my_custom_woocommerce_icons');

function my_custom_woocommerce_icons() {

    $icons  = '<div class="checkout-icons-container">
        
    <img src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/visa02.png" alt="visa" />
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/mastercard.png" alt="mastercard"/>
    </div>';

     echo $icons;
}
```

Comment: For static values, they're fine if not escaped (using WordPress functions), as long as you've ensured the value is good (e.g. special characters are already escaped). But you should not hard-code the site URL. Instead, use [`content_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/content_url/) or any WordPress functions which retrieves an attachment URL by attachment ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to escape values that cannot be changed by someone else.

You should escape output that might be changed by some other source, for example if there is a filter running on the values.

Let's say you are using `wp_upload_dir()` to find the upload directory – and you absolutely should, because the location of that directory can be customized! — then there are various filters in play, so you should escape the final URLs.

Or if you insert your own filter option, so you can change the URL per plugin or child theme – again, you need escaping.

Example:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'];
$payment_icons = [
    'visa'       => $upload_url . '/2022/01/visa02.png',
    'mastercard' => $upload_url . '/2022/01/mastercard.png',
];
$payment_icons = apply_filters( 'theme_payment_icons', $payment_icons );

foreach( $payment_icons as $alt => $url ) {
    printf(
        '<img src="%1$s" alt="%2$s">',
        esc_url( $url ), // we escape as late as possible!
        esc_attr( $alt )    
    );
}
```